# Маршалинг строки Unicode 32

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Атоловская "libfptr10.so" в линуксе работает с 4-х байтовыми символами в строке - Unicode 32.

Как можно задать маршалинг для такой строки?

Я пробовал варианты вроде этого (которые срабатывают под win64 - но там 2-х байтовые символы в строке):

```
MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder value
```

но это для Unicode 32 не срабатывает.
??

Comment: WSTR=UTF-16; ICustomMarshaler